# Spring OAuth2 login with https proxy goes back to http

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

This question has been asked in similar form in the past, but not for the versions I'm using now, plus I've tried what they all mentioned and it didn't seem to work.

I have a Java 11, Spring 5.3, Spring Boot 2.7.9, Spring Sec 5.7.7 web app, packaged as WAR, deployed on a Wildfly 15 web app server and am also using Apache httpd.
The home page is https://reactrax.com and uses ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to talk to Wildfly.
The app has the users authenticate using OAuth2 and Google. However, after login, the page is returned to http://reactrax.com:8080/loginSuccess.
Note that it's now http instead of https and the Wildfly port has been added.

How do I get the login page just to redirect back to the original pre-login page on https://reactrax.com ?

The changes that I've seen recommended include the following, but I haven't been able to find the magic combination to make it all work.

Apache:

- RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
- RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
- ProxyPreserveHost On

Spring properties:

- server.use-forward-headers=true (deprecated in Spring Boot 2.2 in favor of server.forward-headers-strategy)
- server.forward-headers-strategy=native
- server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
- server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto

Spring beans:

- ForwardedHeaderFilter

Comment: Have you tried to use any port but 8080 for your Spring app with login? In spring servlet implementations, there is a `PortMapperImpl` involved at quite a few places and it behaves in manner that is unnatural to me when https and port 8080 (or 80) are involved. You could also try to use absolute URIs for anything related to login (login page, post login URIs, etc.) but it is less simple

Comment: Remember, this is running within Wildfly, so Wildfly is the one listening on 8080 and just forwarding requests to my app. I have configured my app to be the root application on Wildfly.

Comment: and on what port is your app running?

Comment: There is no specified port. It's running within Wildfly and my app's context path, not a port, distinguishes it from other possible web apps deployed to Wildfly.

Comment: I get it. What if you run Wildfly on any other port than 8080 (like 8081)?

Comment: I can't. I have several other web apps running on this Wildfly and that would interfere with their access. Out of curiosity, what should I have been looking for if I changed the port number?

Comment: It makes me think of the issue I reported there: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12307 (could be due to the `PortMapperImpl` behavior too). You might have a look at the other alternative I reference in my last comment: using absolute URIs for anything related to login (I provided with useful hints there)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up throwing the whole kitchen sink at the problem, and it eventually worked, but I'm not sure which part of that made it work. :(